# Javascript input a UTC string

Tags: javascript, date, utc

I'm working on a project right now where I want to get an array of dates between two end points. I've got that code working perfectly when I hard code the start and end date in.

My problem is when I used an input, the code doesn't work. How can I convert a normal date input into a UTC string?

Here's an example of what I'm on about: https://jsfiddle.net/mksvh95y/5/

```
<input type="date" id="bubbles" placeholder = "enter date">

<button onclick="getDate()"> Click me to get date</button>


 <script>
   function getDate(){
       var water = document.getElementById("bubbles").value;
       alert(water);
       //alert(water.toUTCString());

       var fire = new Date (2018,10,15);
       alert(fire);
   }
```

I want the get the 'water' variable to be formatted like the 'fire' variable.

I saw there's .toUTCstring(), but that doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possibly a duplicate of [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results?s=1%7C463.6126), but here's an answer that may be more suitable.

The value of a date input is an ISO 8601 format date string in the format "YYYY-MM-DD", which is what you should see from:

```
alert(water); // something like 2018-06-21
```

The format of the string returned by *Date.prototype.toString* is implementation dependent (though [ECMAScript 2019](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-date.prototype.tostring) will standardise it). That's the format you're getting from:

```
alert(fire) // e.g. Thu Jun 21 2018 00:00:00 GMT+1000 (AEST)
```

One fix is to convert the string from the date input to a Date, then use the default *toString* for both outputs. But your problem then is that parsing of the ISO 8601 date string is UTC, so the dates will be different by the host timezone offset, e.g.

```js
console.log(new Date('2018-06-21').toString()); // 21 Jun 2018
console.log(new Date(2018, 5, 21).toString());  // 21 Jun 2018
```

So you need to parse the string from the input as local using a simple function like:

```js
function parseISOLocal(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(b[0],b[1]-1,b[2]);
}

console.log(parseISOLocal('2018-06-21').toString());
console.log(new Date(2018, 5, 21).toString());
```

If you want to use a library like [*moment.js*](https://momentjs.com), it will parse ISO 8601 formatted date strings as local (which is consistent with ISO 8601), then convert it to a plain Date and use the default *toString*, e.g.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>

<input type="date"
 onchange="console.log(moment(this.value).toDate().toString())">
```

Answer (score -1):

I strongly recommend using the excellent [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/) library for date mainpulation, as native support is poor:

```
function getDate(){
   var water = document.getElementById("bubbles").value;
   var waterMoment = moment(water);
   alert(water.utc().format()); //outputs a UTC date string

   var fire = new Date (2018,10,15);
   alert(fire);
}
```

See the [`moment.utc()` function](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc/) and the [`moment.format()` function](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) for more details.

Comment: I've heard about MomentJs but haven't dove into using it. Does it matter which of these I link to the js, or would any get my going? https://cdnjs.com/libraries/moment.js

Comment: Some of those are locale-specific, so best for particular regions. You don't need those features, so I'd stick with https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js

Comment: An answer shouldn't depend on a library that isn't mentioned or tagged in the OP. Your code has errors, try posting it as a runnable snippet, moment.js can be added as an external library using a CDN (e.g. [*here*](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/moment.js/)).

Comment: Hold on a second... we can't recommend libraries?? As a javascript professional, I find that bizarre and counter-intuitive; please could you point me towards the Stack Overflow guidance that states this.

Also, telling me I have errors in my code without telling me what they are seems... churlish.